# Set Font Size Based On Word Count Jquery

Tags: jquery, fonts, resize

I have multiple articles, but they all need to fit in the same space. Characters are limited to 140. What I'm looking to do is resize the font size based on characters in my paragraph. So if the paragraph has less characters, I would like the font size to get bigger & vise versa.

My code below doesn't seem to be working and was wondering if someone would be able to help me?

What's happening at the moment, it seems to be taking the last else, because the font size from all paragraphs are 8em :(

Very much appreciate any help & thanks in advance!

Here is the code:

```
    $(function(){
    var $quote = $(".question p");
    var $numWords = $quote.text().split("").length;     
    if (($numWords >= 1) && ($numWords < 20)) {
        $quote.css("font-size", "2.2em");
    }
    else if (($numWords >= 20) && ($numWords < 60)) {
        $quote.css("font-size", "1.8em");
    }
    else if (($numWords >= 60) && ($numWords < 100)) {
        $quote.css("font-size", "1.2em");
    }
    else if (($numWords >= 100) && ($numWords < 140)) {
        $quote.css("font-size", "0.9em");
    }
    else {
        $quote.css("font-size", "0.8em");
    }           
});
```

Comment: There's a plug-in for this already :)

https://gist.github.com/mekwall/1263939

Comment: This won't fix your issue, but you should probably rename your $numWords variable, as you're counting characters when you split on "", not words.

Comment: Hey it seems to work ok in this fiddle > http://jsfiddle.net/u3fyu/

Comment: @vletech nope, add multiple paragraphs with different character length, still having the same issue.

Comment: working jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gCKWF/

Comment: @ChrisC yeah I may do that, didn't think var name really mattered though?

Comment: @Diodeus still pretty new to jquery / js and tried this, but also doesn't seem to be working. I also need something that changes EMs not pixels. Thank you though.

Comment: The name doesn't matter to the browser executing the code: It's just good practice to use meaningful variable names.

Comment: @ChrisC Maybe I'm explaining it wrong, but the code above seems to be changing the text on all paragraphs to the same font size, even though they have different character lengths. I've just tried that code above. Here's an example of what I need http://yourquestions.mcdonalds.ca/

Comment: Ah, I see, that explains it :)  See my answer for a working response: You just need to treat each paragraph separately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is you're not treating each paragraph individually: see http://jsfiddle.net/wkEMK/1/

```
$(function(){
    $(".question p").each(function () {
        var numChars = $(this).text().length;     
        if ((numChars >= 1) && (numChars < 20)) {
            $(this).css("font-size", "2.2em");
        }
        else if ((numChars >= 20) && (numChars < 60)) {
            $(this).css("font-size", "1.8em");
        }
        else if ((numChars >= 60) && (numChars < 100)) {
            $(this).css("font-size", "1.2em");
        }
        else if ((numChars >= 100) && (numChars < 140)) {
            $(this).css("font-size", "0.9em");
        }
        else {
            $(this).css("font-size", "0.8em");
        }           
    });
});
```

Your original code was getting the character count for ALL paragraphs that matched '.question p'.  e.g. If you had two paragraphs, one with ten characters, the other with twenty characters, your JS would run once with a total of thirty, rather than processing each paragraph in turn.

Answer (score 3):

Do it like this using the [.css](http://api.jquery.com/css/) function.. This way it will change each p elements font-size according to the number of chars inside each p element

```
$(function(){         
    $(".question p").css('font-size',function(){
        var $numWords = $(this).text().length; // get length of text for current p element
        if (($numWords >= 1) && ($numWords < 20)) {
            return "2.2em";
        }
        else if (($numWords >= 20) && ($numWords < 60)) {
            return "1.8em";
        }
        else if (($numWords >= 60) && ($numWords < 100)) {
            return "1.2em";
        }
        else if (($numWords >= 100) && ($numWords < 140)) {
            return "0.9em";
        }
        else {
            return "0.8em";
        }           
    });    
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/AHMXf/)